# Map for React Native Web With Expo and Metro

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, react-native-web, expo-web

I am building a hybrid app with React Native Expo. My struggle is that my app needs a map and needs to be functional on mobile and web. To have a map with React Native I found several libraries, but there is always a problem :

- react-native-maps : No support for web. (https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps)
- @teovilla/react-native-web-maps : Config with Webpack, but I use Metro (to be able to use Expo Router)
- react-native-leaflet : Use Webview, so not compatible for web
- MapBox SDK : cannot be used with Expo Go (https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/plugin/install.md)

I tried all these libraries but I was not being able to achieve the rendering of my map in web.

My goal is just to use a map with React Native Expo in web using Metro. Maybe I'm missing something, but I really don't know how to display a map. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that we can use `@teovilla/react-native-web-maps` simply with Metro too. To do so, we can create a `mymap.web.js` and `mymap.js` component. React Native will be smart enough to pick the proper extension for the platform being built. In the first component we can import `@teovilla/react-native-web-maps` and in the second we can import `react-native-maps`.

```js
// /components/mymap.web.js
import MapView from "@teovilla/react-native-web-maps";
export default MapView;
```

```js
// /components/mymap.js
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
export default MapView;
```

Now in our code, we can import our component like so (path to adapt) :

```js
import MapView from '../components/mymap';
```