# Unable to use react-native-web-maps in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, react-native-web, expo-router

I'm trying to add a map to my project, so I used `react-native-maps` in native, and `@teovilla/react-native-web-maps` in web.

Here is the dependencies in package.json

```json
 "dependencies": {
    .....
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@teovilla/react-native-web-maps": "^0.9.3",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    .....
  },
```

I tried several ways to set up config for `@teovilla/react-native-web-maps` but it's still not working.

###### 1. `@teovilla/react-native-web-maps` config with Webpack, but I use Metro (with expo router v2). So I tried the way in [Map for React Native Web With Expo and Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647066/map-for-react-native-web-with-expo-and-metro)

```js
// /components/mymap.web.js
import MapView from "@teovilla/react-native-web-maps";
export default MapView;
// /components/mymap.js
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
export default MapView;

// in my component
import MapView from '../components/mymap';
```

compile success, but the map did not show in web.

###### 2. set the webpack.config.js as the docs

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

  config.resolve.alias['react-native-maps'] = '@teovilla/react-native-web-maps';

  return config;
};
```

compile failed

###### 3. add the config in metro.config.js (?)

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname, {
  // [Web-only]: Enables CSS support in Metro.
  isCSSEnabled: true,
});
config.resolver.sourceExts.push("mjs");

config.resolver.extraNodeModules = {
  ...config.resolver.extraNodeModules,
  "react-native-maps": require.resolve(
    process.env.EXPO_WEBPACK_PLATFORM === "web"
      ? "@teovilla/react-native-web-maps"
      : "react-native-maps",
  ),
};

module.exports = config;
```

still compile failed